Are `type Hello = str` style type alias definitions (PEP 695) "supported" in any way by Sphinx + autodoc?
(Here's the GitHub repo for this example. It includes instructions on running the example and optional scripts to help automate building the documentation.)
Problem
I am using Sphinx + autodoc + autosummary + intersphinx to generate some documentation for a Python project.
As is expected (from type aliases not being properly supported by Sphinx), links aren't created to internal documentation for type aliases I have created. However, it should be possible for autodoc to expand the type alias, but this is not happening either.
Previous solutions discussed for the problem are outdated in that Hello: TypeAlias = str is no longer the canonical way to define type aliases in Python (see PEP 695 and the documentation it points to).
type Hello = str style annotations should be supported according to this GitHub discussion, but I still cannot get type alias expansion to occur. Why is that?
Python Code
Here's the Python code that I have documented using Sphinx + ReST.
"""Does ``intersphinx`` do its thing?"""

from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Any

import polars as pl

type Hello = str

def make_df(
    greeting: Hello, some_datatype: pl.DataType, some_stuff: Any
) -> pl.DataFrame:
    print(greeting)
    return pl.DataFrame()

My index.rst looks like, based on this SO answer:
myproject documentation
=======================

This is a test to see if intersphinx works as we expect.

.. autosummary::
  :toctree: _autosummary
  :recursive:

  myproject

My conf.py looks like:
import os
import sys
from pathlib import Path

# Configuration file for the Sphinx documentation builder.
#
# For the full list of built-in configuration values, see the documentation:
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html

# -- Project information -----------------------------------------------------
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#project-information

project = "myproject"

# -- Project setup -----------------------------------------------------
#

exclude_patterns = [
    "_build",
    "Thumbs.db",
    ".DS_Store",
    ".venv",
    ".vscode",
    "analysis_*",
    "dist",
    "excel",
    "myproject-notebooks",
    "*.md",
    "*.sh",
    "*.toml",
    "./**/__pycache__",
    "*.pyc",
    "docs",
]


def get_main_folder(assumed_folder_name: str) -> Path:
    """Get the full path of the main folder, given its assumed name."""
    cwd = Path(os.getcwd()).absolute()
    # Traverse up from the given path to the root
    for parent in cwd.parents:
        if parent.name == assumed_folder_name:
            return parent

    if cwd.name == assumed_folder_name:
        return cwd

    raise ValueError(
        f"Current working directory does not contain {assumed_folder_name} as a parent!"
    )


myproject_path = get_main_folder("sphinx-doc-test").joinpath("myproject")
print(f"{myproject_path=}")

source_folders = [myproject_path]
print(f"using source folders: {source_folders}")

for folder in source_folders:
    sys.path.insert(0, folder)


# -- General configuration ---------------------------------------------------
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#general-configuration

extensions = [
    "sphinx.ext.autodoc",
    "sphinx.ext.autosummary",
    "sphinx.ext.intersphinx",
]

templates_path = ["_templates"]

autosummary_generate = True  # Turn on autosummary

autodoc_default_options = {
    "members": True,  # Include members in the documentation
    "undoc-members": True,  # Include undocumented members
    "private-members": False,  # Include private members (starting with _)
    "show-inheritance": True,  # Show base classes
}
autodoc_typehints = "both"

# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/intersphinx.html#configuration

intersphinx_mapping = {
    "python": ("https://docs.python.org/3", None),
    "polars": ("https://docs.pola.rs/api/python/stable", None),
}

# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/todo.html#configuration

todo_include_todos = True


# -- Options for HTML output -------------------------------------------------
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#options-for-html-output

html_theme = "alabaster"
html_static_path = ["_static"]

I am using:
dependencies = [
    "polars>=1.6.0",
    "sphinx>=8.0.2",
]
requires-python = ">= 3.12"


The GitHub discussion that you refer to is about sphinx-autoapi, which is a different extension (an alternative to autodoc/autosummary).

Current Sphinx issue #11561 is the canonical FR requesting support for PEP 695 type aliases. The alternative I'm currently using is the older syntax with the workarounds described in Sphinx issue #10785. None of the discussions you linked (both with answers by the same user) provide a working example of effectively using the older syntax, so see issue #10785 for the closest alternative - following this example it should be possible to write RST to get a workaround.

Apparently this was solved to some extent with Sphinx 7.4.0 I haven't tested it further.
